# Express: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I was having a problem to post on an api created with Express.js and SQL Server DB, until found the next solution:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sql = require('mssql');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});

const dbConfig = {
    user: "daUser",
    password: "daPass",
    server: "daServer",
    database: "daDB"
};

const executeQuery = function (res, query, parameters) {
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            var request = new sql.Request();

            parameters.forEach(function (p) {
                request.input(p.name, p.sqltype, p.value);
            });

            request.query(query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(err);
                    sql.close();
                }
                else {
                    res.send(result.recordsets);
                    sql.close();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

//GET ALL
app.get("/api/InvoiceRequestTaxes", function (req, res) {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM [InvoiceRequestTaxes]";
    executeQuery(res, query);
});

//GET BY InvoiceRequestId
app.get("/api/InvoiceRequestTaxes/:idRequest", function (req, res) {
    const requestId = req.params.idRequest;
    var query = "SELECT * FROM [InvoiceRequestTaxes] WHERE InvoiceRequestId=" + requestId;
    executeQuery(res, query);
});

//POST
app.post("/api/InvoiceRequestTaxes", function (req, res) {
    const parameters = [
        { name: 'InvoiceRequestId', sqltype: sql.Int, value: req.body.InvoiceRequestId },
        { name: 'IdProduct', sqltype: sql.Int, value: req.body.IdProduct },
        { name: 'Price', sqltype: sql.Money, value: req.body.Price },
        { name: 'Cost', sqltype: sql.Money, value: req.body.Cost },
        { name: 'Margin', sqltype: sql.Money, value: req.body.Margin },
        { name: 'BaseMarginIVA', sqltype: sql.Money, value: req.body.BaseMarginIVA },
        { name: 'BaseCostIVA', sqltype: sql.Money, value: req.body.BaseCostIVA },
        { name: 'IVA', sqltype: sql.Money, value: req.body.IVA },
        { name: 'StatusId', sqltype: sql.Int, value: req.body.StatusId },
        { name: 'DateCreated', sqltype: sql.VarChar, value: req.body.DateCreated },
        { name: 'DateUpdated', sqltype: sql.VarChar, value: req.body.DateUpdated }
    ];
    var query = "INSERT INTO [InvoiceRequestTaxes](InvoiceRequestId, IdProduct, Price, Cost, Margin, BaseMarginIVA, BaseCostIVA, IVA, StatusId, DateCreated, DateUpdated) VALUES(@InvoiceRequestId, @IdProduct, @Price, @Cost, @Margin, @BaseMarginIVA, @BaseCostIVA, @IVA, @StatusId, @DateCreated, @DateUpdated)";
    executeQuery(res, query, parameters);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port: ${PORT}`)
});
```

As you can see, i have to declare on `const executeQuery` the parameters. My problem comes when i'm triying to make a get, because the console shows the next message:

> Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

How can i make the get method while i'm not sending any param?

I tried passing the params only on the post like this:

```
app.post("/api/InvoiceRequestTaxes", function (req, res, parameters) {
    const parameters = [
        { name: 'InvoiceRequestId', sqltype: sql.Int, value: req.body.InvoiceRequestId },
        { name: 'IdProduct', sqltype: sql.Int, value: req.body.IdProduct },
        { name: 'Price', sqltype: sql.Money, value: req.body.Price },
        { name: 'Cost', sqltype: sql.Money, value: req.body.Cost },
        { name: 'Margin', sqltype: sql.Money, value: req.body.Margin },
        { name: 'BaseMarginIVA', sqltype: sql.Money, value: req.body.BaseMarginIVA },
        { name: 'BaseCostIVA', sqltype: sql.Money, value: req.body.BaseCostIVA },
        { name: 'IVA', sqltype: sql.Money, value: req.body.IVA },
        { name: 'StatusId', sqltype: sql.Int, value: req.body.StatusId },
        { name: 'DateCreated', sqltype: sql.VarChar, value: req.body.DateCreated },
        { name: 'DateUpdated', sqltype: sql.VarChar, value: req.body.DateUpdated }
    ];

parameters.forEach(function (p) {
                request.input(p.name, p.sqltype, p.value);
            });

    var query = "INSERT INTO [InvoiceRequestTaxes](InvoiceRequestId, IdProduct, Price, Cost, Margin, BaseMarginIVA, BaseCostIVA, IVA, StatusId, DateCreated, DateUpdated) VALUES(@InvoiceRequestId, @IdProduct, @Price, @Cost, @Margin, @BaseMarginIVA, @BaseCostIVA, @IVA, @StatusId, @DateCreated, @DateUpdated)";
    executeQuery(res, query, parameters);
});
```

But now i get another error on the console:

> request.input  is not a function

Hope someone can help me.

I'm using Express.js, Node and SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a null check for parameters in the function executeQuery.

```
const executeQuery = function (res, query, parameters) {
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            var request = new sql.Request();
            if(parameters && parameters.length>0){
                parameters.forEach(function (p) {
                    request.input(p.name, p.sqltype, p.value);
                });
            }

            request.query(query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(err);
                    sql.close();
                }
                else {
                    res.send(result.recordsets);
                    sql.close();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `parameters` function argument is not defined.

```
const executeQuery = function (res, query, parameters) {
    ...
    parameters.forEach(function (p) {
 // ^ parameters is not defined when you call the function
        request.input(p.name, p.sqltype, p.value);
    });
}
```

At your call you have this :

```
executeQuery(res, query);
```

Which leaves `parameters` undefined.